# How to hide a <div> on non-permalink pages on Tumblr

Tags: css, html, navigation, themes, tumblr

I have a navigational  which sits in the right margin of the page, and is basically just a series of anchor links that scroll with the 'fixed' property. This works fine inside the permalink page of the post, but still appears under the section pages, which are just /tagged/x pages.

Here's an example of the code which is inside the post html:

```
<div class="contents">
<p align="center"><strong>NAVIGATE</strong></p>
<a href="#intro">Introduction</a><br>
<a href="#jcole">J Cole</a><br>
<a href="#cudi">Kanye & Kid Cudi</a><br>
<a href="#joeyb">Joey Bada$$</a><br>
<a href="#mchg">Magna Carta Holy Grail</a><br>
<a href="#out1">Other News</a><br>
<a href="#out2">Other Highs</a> </div>
```

Then the div is styled as such in the theme code:

```
.contents{
position:fixed;
width: 220px;
top:300px;
right: 20px;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: right;
background: black;}
```

How do I get the  to appear only on permalink pages?

Thanks,
Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do get code to only appear on post permalinks you need to include a combination of blocks.

```
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Date}
    <!-- code placed in here will *only* render on post permalinks -->
{/block:Date}{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

The `PermalinkPage` block is pretty self explanatory. The trick here is using the `Date` block. Pages, you see, don't have dates assigned to them, they are just static content. Only post permalinks have a date assigned to them so you can use it to help filter your conditionals.

### Update

If this content is being entered individually on each post you'll need to go a slightly different route. In the `<head>` of your theme file you should be able to do this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    {block:PermalinkPage}{block:Date}
    .contents { display: block; }
    {/block:Date}{/block:PermalinkPage}
</style>
```

Then in your original styles for the `.contents` block, just make sure to make it be `display: none;`.

Now it will only be display block on post permalinks.

Comment: I thought that the solution would somehow involve the blocks. However, would this work inside the post code of each individual post (because the <div> in each post would be unique so it couldn't be put into the theme code)?

Comment: This needs to be placed inside the theme code. I'll update the code with an alternate method.